# ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core 7 MVC startup and session migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core and I am trying to migrate a template we used for all our apps, that used .NET framework 4.x. I was able to get the app to use my SSO provider, import the database into it and hook it up.

Where am I stuck at the moment is how to load something into a session or memory as the application starts up.

The framework template worked in these steps:

1. Authenticate with Windows (AD)
2. On session start, in `global.asax`, get some data about you from the database and load it into an object. This contains data about your roles and such inside the app.
3. Put that object in a session
4. Push person to a view based on if their user object is authenticated or not.

In my .NET 7 app, I would like to do something similar but I'm unsure how to do it since it looks like sessions are not meant to be used this way anymore and I'm unsure where to do step 2 in .NET Core so that its happening before you ever get pushed to a view since session start is no longer there.

The steps in my head would be:

1. Authenticate with our SSO provider (done)
2. Get data from the database on the person for app roles/etc. Where do I do this step in the `program.cs`?
3. Store that object somewhere so it can be used at any time.
4. Push person to a view based on if their user object is authenticated or not.

Comment: You can use Entity Framework as ORM, create an instance of your db context and then inject your repository so that you can call any ORM method. To store your object, I would use also the db, but it depends of your goal with the storage. About the authentication, if you use some auth token as JWT, you can use HttpContext to easily get data (claim) about each user by their token, and then you can push this person or do something else with it

Comment: This question is very broad and it would be hard to give an answer without knowing more about your actual requirements. Microsoft docs on using an external SSO provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio . Right at the bottom there is a link to a section on persisting claims using an authentication cookie.

Comment: Session-state today is kinda unfashionable because it means you have to deal with host affinity - or have an expensive Redis instance running. Fortunately it turns out that 80% of the time you simply don't need to keep anything in-memory and better alternatives exist (e.g. using the client _front-channel_ to hold authX tickets, using persisted blob storage for intermediate big-data and large file processing, etc etc).

Comment: _"Get data from the database on the person for app roles/etc. Where do I do this step in the program.cs?"_ - assuming the amount of data you're getting is under 1-2KB, then you would store this data as Claims within the user's `HttpContext.User` and let ASP.NET Core handle Claim serialization and authX ticket management for you.